# What is the meaning of string[::-1][::-1][::-1]?

Tags: python, slice

```
word = "hello"
word[::-1][::-1][::-1]
```

I see that it reverses `word` with slices when put through an interpreter, but how exactly does this work with three `[]`?

Comment: it just does it *again* and *again*. So `word[::-1][::-1][::-1]` could get broken down into `result = word[::-1]; result = result[::-1]; result = result[::-1]`

Comment: you can do it with first slice , second slice reverse it back tand the 3rd slice recerse it again

Answer (score 1):

```
word = "hello"
word[::-1][::-1][::-1]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
word = "hello"
word = word[::-1]
word = word[::-1]
word[::-1]
```

Easy subscript (`[]`) works on the results of the previous. We could also make this more explicit with parentheses.

```
word = "hello"
( ( word[::-1] )[::-1] )[::-1]
```

In this case, the string is reversed, then that reversed string is reversed back to the original order, then it's reversed again. The word "overkill" comes to mind.